# How to make a button change a variable in a script then take that script into another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computer-science

So i want to make a button change the variable in one script. Then i want another script to get that variable from the first script. How do i do this.

I have tried somethings but im not sure if i did them correctly

When i try it like in the code below. Then it gives me the message:

'The type or namespace name 'jumpscript' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

```
Jump.cs

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool jump = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    public void JumpOnClick()
    {
        jump = true;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}

PlayerMovement.cs

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Joystick joystick;
    public jumpscript Jump;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (joystick.Horizontal >= .2f)
        {
            horizontalMove = runSpeed;
        } else if (joystick.Horizontal <= -.2f)

        {
            horizontalMove = -runSpeed;
        } else
        {
            horizontalMove = 0f;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, Jump.jump);
        Jump.jump = false;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I got the character to jump but the character is always jumping.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Joystick joystick;
    public Jump jumpScript;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;
    bool Jump = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (jumpScript.jump == true)
        {
            Jump = true;
        }

        if (joystick.Horizontal >= .2f)
        {
            horizontalMove = runSpeed;
        } else if (joystick.Horizontal <= -.2f)

        {
            horizontalMove = -runSpeed;
        } else
        {
            horizontalMove = 0f;
        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, Jump);
        Jump = false;
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Jump : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool jump = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update


    public void JumpOnClick()
    {
        jump = true;
        jump = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so first thing to note, I am assuming both of these scripts are on the one gameobject.

You have to create a local variable out of the jump script. You can accomplish it like this:

```
private Jump jumpScript;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    jump = this.GetComponent<Jump>();
    jump.JumpOnClick();
}
```

Comment: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration     Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration   Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
   Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected    invalid token '{' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Also could you explain where i should put it

Comment: So that code block should be going into your PlayerMovement class i think, as this is the class that you want your public method called from. The example i provided is a bit generic and you may have to change it for your use case.

Comment: You have issues because you declared the variable as `Jump jumpScript` but you're trying to assign `jump = this.GetComponent<Jump>()`